# Solving a coupled eigen value problem

Tags: eigenvalues, eigensystem

I have the following problem:

$$\begin{bmatrix}A &B \\C& D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda I_m & 0 \\ 0& \mu I_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\y\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are matrices, $I_m,I_n$ are identity matrices of sizes $m,n$, $x,y$ are vectors and $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are scalars.

How does one solve such a problem?

Comment: That's not an eigenvalue problem. You will want $\lambda$ and $\mu$ to be the same.

Comment: This looks like a two-parameter eigenvalue problem in a non-standard form. 
I would expect that it is possible to transform it to the standard form, under certain conditions.
Google: two-parameter eigenvalue problem. See, for example, [Philip A. Browne: Numerical Methods for Two Parameter Eigenvalue Problems.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.722.1727&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @WolfgangBangerth .. yes, making $\mu,\lambda$ to be the same makes it a trivial eigenvalue problem, but I am particularly looking for the case when they are different.

Comment: @wim Thanks for the reference, though I don't think it is the same type of problem: as per the reference, a two parameter eigenvalue problem is defined as:
$\begin{bmatrix} A_1 & 0 \\ 0 & A_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda B_1+\mu C_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda B_2+\mu C_2  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$
which is different from the the one I posted (for one, there is no coupling between $x$ and $y$).

Comment: @udax: I see. With a standard eigenvalue problem one requires that $x\neq 0$. I think that in your case $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ is not sufficient. Otherwise the simple problem
$\begin{bmatrix}1 &1 \\1& 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda \cdot  1 & 0 \\ 0& \mu \cdot 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\y\end{bmatrix}
$, would have infinitely many solutions for $\mu$ and $\lambda$. Probably
$||x|| = ||y|| =1$ is a reasonable requirement here?

Comment: @udax The problem can be transformed into a generalized eigenvalue problem for one of the parameters fixed ($\lambda$ or $\mu$) and there is an inverse for either B or C.

Comment: @Bort Yes, that is possible. The only downside is then one needs to do a parameter sweep over the fixed parameter to get the full range of allowed $\lambda,\mu$.

Comment: @wim that's an interesting observation. I don't have a good response so far.

Comment: Are you sure there's no transformation you can perform that would separate the equations? Something like in this paper: https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.43.9649

Comment: How many solutions would you like to find? Because there would be infinity many, namely you find $n+m$ eigenvalues for every constraint that $\mu=\alpha\,\lambda$ where $\alpha$ can be any scalar. Not sure if $\alpha$ has to be non-zero, but either way there are infinite possibilities for $\alpha$. So without more constraints the number of solutions unbounded.